# Prolog beginner question about scheduling and assigning groups

Tags: list, prolog, timetable

It's descended into just randomness since I obviously completely can't feel the logic of this logic, even though over a year ago I felt I was getting somewhere, then didn't look at it until now, and it's all just a complete random mystery of what thing is stopping this from working.

```
pref(mark,a).
pref(bart,a).
get_pref(A,[X|Y]):- pref(X,A).
get_pref(A,[X|Y]):- pref(X,A),get_pref(A,Y).

timetable([Cl,L1],[C2,L2]):-  
    All = [S1,S2,S3,S4],
    L1 = [S1,S2],
    L2 = [S3,S4],
    get_pref(Cl,L1),            
    get_pref(C2,L2),
    list_to_set(All,All).
```

with the query `timetable([a,[S1,S2]],[b,[S3,S4]])`

No results are found. Then I added `pref(mary,b).` and `pref(sue,b).` and I get 16 results which at least don't have duplicated names show switched position of names as well as oddly enough a `_` variable either no times, once or twice.

In the initial statements, or predicates (if that's what they're called), I've seen some tutorials show a `get_pref(A,[]):-` additionally, looking like it's 'setting something up', sometimes a `:- !` on things that all seem roughly related but it's all gibberish the way my dyslectic/adhd/autistic brain interprets the examples and tutorials.

I am trying to get towards building a comprehensive scheduling algorithm but these first stages are a time-consuming nightmare of trial and error. Do you have any pointers on the direction and strategy to take with this, or links to sites or videos that actually, once and for all, allow those of us who are used to different forms of problem solving, to bridge the gap?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to teach yourself Prolog? or Did you take a Prolog class at a university level?

Comment: `get_pref(A,[X|Y]):- pref(X,A).
get_pref(A,[X|Y]):- pref(X,A),get_pref(A,Y).` What one would expect to be your base case is not a base case.

Comment: Trying myself :/ It sort of looks like what other examples and tutorials have, and seems to align with my understanding of the logic, while there is still a good amount of voodoo mystery magic surrounding how one part speaks to the others and ultimately determines if something is true or not. What would therefore constitute a base case, in this example? Thanks for any help!

Comment: The first useful rule of learning Prolog is to forget everything you know about programming. Seriously. All of that baggage of prior programming knowledge will just cause you grief.

Comment: Then learn the rules of [syntactic unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)#Examples_of_syntactic_unification_of_first-order_terms) until you see the results without even thinking. In the table in the link `=` does not mean equals, it means unifies. See what I mean by baggage that will cause you grief. `=` is not equals.

Comment: I hate to say it but the code is of no help in trying to understand your problem and you don't really describe the problem as a teacher would explain it. So can't really help or answer the question any more than already noted.

Comment: `list_to_set(All,All)` is **very** doubious

Comment: `oddly enough a _ variable either no times, once or twice.`: change `get_pref(A,[X|Y]):- pref(X,A).` to `get_pref(A,[X]):- pref(X,A).`

Comment: @GuyCoder I get that I need to 'unlearn' everything I know and am basically going through trial and error of ways to interpret the underlying logic. In this case I am trying to create a basic example of a timetable where 2 students have both expressed a preference for class 'a', so would like to ideally return the result that both go in 'a', irrespective of order, and the other class 'b' has 2 unattended seats.

Comment: @CapelliC why would that be *very* dubious? It removes a whole bunch of results, makes it quicker, and in other larger examples I had in the past seemed quicker than any findall() or setof() that I had tried, not to mention doing giant lists of /= between variables. Any yes you code changed worked for when there are 4 students, but I just cannot see how/why. When I returned it to just the 2 students there were no results, so somehow I want to allow for `_` variables to be returned if no answer is found, or would the way to do this would be to add `pref(no1,_).pref(no2,_).` into the mix?

Comment: Then the final thing would be ignoring the order; that S1 or S2 can be in either place, same with S3 and S4, basically resulting in just 1 result...

Comment: `list_to_set(All,All)` is a problem because the input `All` is the same as the output `All`. There is only one variable in the call, not two. `All` is unified with `All`.

Comment: `trial and error` is not a way to learn Prolog. A better place to start is with [Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.let.rug.nl/bos/lpn//). If you really want to learn Prolog take it from a good in person University course. Be aware that not all University courses for Prolog are good.

Comment: Are you on the Prolog discord Coder?

Comment: Even having the two statements `get_pref(A,[X]):- pref(X,A).
 get_pref(A,[X|Y]):- pref(X,A),get_pref(A,Y).` is currently insane for me. I understand that combinations are returned when they are true, but there has to be a sequence here that determines things to be true. What points at what? Do the proofs go up and down, or to both. It's about visualising the direction and flow of the logic, and I haven't come across a tutorial that doesn't speak to its readers with technical abstraction and not simple, first-principles thinking. This is where I struggle, and no doubt loads of others too.

Comment: It reminds me of that time when I attempted to study MA level maths after about a 15 year break after finishing high school maths. One of the courses was Complex Analysis, which I could not wrap my head around because I did not understand complex numbers as a foundation, and nothing I asked or read could explain it to me, until one guy gave me THE way to think about it basically on a napkin in a dining room in an unrelated situation. In 3 minutes it made perfect sense. I believe everything can be explained if presented right, so I look for such explanations and not mindlessly follow courses...

Comment: Try this: "The Power of Prolog" https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFFeNyzCEQDS4KCecugmotg (we also need "The Power of ASP?")

Comment: Thanks @DavidTonhofer, had a quick look, looks good! What do you mean by ASP?

Comment: @MikeyB ["Answer Set Programming"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer_set_programming), a different approach to logic programming than Prolog. Greatly interesting. The feel is of a very complicated ray gun from the future.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Interesting, do you think it would be an even better tool for solving timetabling optimisation with hundreds of actors - not just teachers and rooms, but rooms/classes, teacher preferences and student preferences? EDIT: But of course if I stayed with Prolog, which I probably should if it's 'easier', is it itself capable or solving for such large sets of data? I did some preliminary tests before without CLP and things got out of hand very quickly...

Comment: @MikeyB Difficult to say. If you just want to do optimization, you certainly want to use Prolog+CLP. I don't know enough about ASP, it's like a "more general Prolog". But you could also take a good look at system dedicated to optimization & solving, as opposed to more general programming as for Prolog. Here is [MiniZinc](https://www.minizinc.org/resources.html), I would really look in that direction,

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Thanks for the suggestions! Looking into MiniZinc, which I had heard of before but never investigated, opened up the world of CP paradigms. It led me to this http://picat-lang.org/picatbook2015.html just started reading, will investigate further....and hope that I can incorporate it into Nodejs without having to learn how to build compilers, transpilers, or whatever would be needed to merge it with my js code.

Comment: Whole book here http://picat-lang.org/picatbook2015/constraint_solving_and_planning_with_picat.pdf

Comment: @MikeyB Right, Picat is also a possibility and can be used "as replacement for" Prolog. We have an embarrassment of riches!

Comment: Yeah as I read on I see it's a whole 'subculture' with at least a dozen variations and languages. Now it becomes a problem to identify which one will best suit my needs while causing minimum hassle to learn and integrate into a node.js app.

Comment: I would bet on picat. Right now I'm going to build from source ver. 3.1, then will try with WebAssembly... Have never done it before (picat+wasm, I mean), if succesful will let you know...

Comment: @DavidTonhofer: I had a rather poor experience when tried to 'migrate' Prolog to Picat. Maybe it's better now, since they introduced a more prolog-ish syntax...

Comment: @CapelliC that would be interesting, please do let me know. How long could such a process take? Right now reached a wall with figuring our how to get minizinc working on node. I really want this for a practical application, not just for fun and curiosity :)

Comment: Not sure, since seems I've lost my emscripten setup (I'm working on Linux) so I need to recover it before. Could be anything between a day and a month, sorry...

Comment: But do you know Picat enough, or have found a sample sufficiently similar to your project ?

Comment: Damn guys, don't pull in WebAssembly too. That can become arbitrarily complex. You need Gyro Gearloose skills.

Comment: No, no worries, I'm just curious, I have nothing to contribute unfortunately, I'm just a javascript developer trying to build components for a web app. And no, I don't know Picat, but since I'm know next to nothing in Prolog then whatever I learn will be from scratch. I just want to make sure the language I do pick will eventually be able to cope in my particular use-case, as described in an earlier comment

Comment: But perhaps it's a question of compromises and MiniZinc would be easier for me than Prolog and Picat, while doing a 'good enough' job at my problem? And by good enough I mean does it and doesn't take an age to arrive at optimal results, and doesn't take an age for me to get it working on the FreeBSD server. Preliminary npm install attempts already hit that snag.

Comment: @MikeyB I would go with the MZ as it is specifically meant for optimization/satisfiability poroblems and not a general programming system. However, you will need to look at getting data in and out of that system, too. Text exchange?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Thanks, things are pointing that way. I have the IDE loaded on Windows, can start learning. Just want to get it up on the hosting server to make sure I'm not wasting my time learning something I won't be using. Perhaps I now need to learn the whole linux paradigm of binaries, compilers and all that CLI stuff. What do you mean by text exchange?

Comment: @MikeyB Well, eventually you will want to query the program, for example by wrapping into a CGI script started from a webserver. Unless you just interrogate the program from the command line? (As an example, SWI-Prolog has an integrated webserver + extra code so that you can actually query it directly from javascript).

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Picat is rather difficult to compile *correctly* to Wasm, and I had to fix also some Emscripten configuration problem, due to the rather old Ubuntu distro I'm running (16.04). I do have a compiled sistem, but it generate a signal() on launch, and doesn't work. So I'm working on porting to Wasm [my toy hhprolog](https://github.com/CapelliC/hhprolog/tree/master/ems), and [my old interpreter](https://github.com/CapelliC/IL) (that seems to perform more or less as scryer-prolog). Baby steps....

Comment: Hey no apology needed! Sounds interesting, but I'm too new at all this to really make sense of any of what you created, how it works, the context it first in, etc. I myself have gone down the MiniZinc root and finally, after 3 days of figuring out how, have it and a solver compiled on the freeBSD server (never did much linuz/CLI stuff before) and working with node. Today starts the learning of how models for it work :)